# drupal 7 users blog address selection

Tags: nodes

I installed the blog module.
Now I want that each user before posting first blog, choose their blog address.
I want that they can choose their own blog address.
For example user A can select that his blog be on `http://mydomain.com/myblogaddress`.
How to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do that adding a field to user, say **Blog address** `field_blog_address`. Then you can use tokens in pathauto pattern configuration page to set the blog path as `[user:field_blog_address]`.

Comment: OK.I now this.but it has several problem.For example if a user have an address same as another user?or if a user dont choose an address?